# Replacing a sum with an integral in the limit of a large system

Tags: statistical-mechanics, phase-space

I have the expression $$\sum_{\vec{x}} \sum_{\vec{p}} e^{-\beta \, h(x,p)}$$ for a single particle in a box with volume V and the energy h(x,p). Then I have to bring it in an exercise to the form $$\frac{1}{(2\pi\hbar)^3}\int_{V} d^3x \int d^3p\,  e^{-\beta \, h(x,p)}.$$ I think that I got it for the $\vec{p}$-integral: There is the relation $\vec{p} = \hbar \vec{k}$ and also the expression $\frac{(2\pi)^3}{V}$ for the volume per state in the $\vec{k}$-space. Then I can write my sums as $$\frac{V}{(2\pi\hbar)^3}\sum_{\vec{x}} \sum_{\vec{p}} \frac{(2\pi\hbar)^3}{V} e^{-\beta \, h(x,p)} \approx \frac{V}{(2\pi\hbar)^3}\sum_{\vec{x}} \int d^3p \,e^{-\beta \, h(x,p)} $$ where the approximation is valid for large V. But how do I convert the $\vec{x}$-sum to the integral? If I compare the result with my expression, it seems like i have to exchange the sum with the expression $\frac{1}{V} \int_{V}d^3x$ but I don't know why this holds.